# program to find individual word count in a para

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, data-structures

This is program to count individual word count in a variable `para` as an input.

I tried this by using linked list.

Here variable `complete` is an array that acts like a hash code and stores all alphabets and I am linking new word as per the hash and if there is same word then I am increasing the count. This is the logic I followed.

But the thing is in the program it is not going into a particular part of the code which is written to take repeated words and it is not increasing the count.

This is my code can any one help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define NULL 0
struct wordcount 
{
char *s;
int count;
struct wordcount *next;
};
struct checkletter
{
char alph;
struct wordcount *next;
};
struct wordcount * create(char *);
main()
{
char *c,*s1,*intm;
char hastlet;
int hash[26],len,i,k=0,r,j,m=0,t,flag=0;
struct checkletter complete[26];
struct wordcount *node;
clrscr();
for(r=0;r<=25;r++)
{   complete[r].alph=r+97;
    complete[r].next=NULL;
}
for(r=0;r<=25;r++)
{
    printf("%c",complete[r].alph);
}
printf("\n");
printf("Enter the para :");
gets(c);
len=strlen(c);
    //arranging the words and putting them with count
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{       k=0;
    intm='\0';
    if(c[i]==' ')
    {       for(j=m;j<i;j++)
        {
            intm[k]=c[j];
            k++;

        }
        intm[k]='\0';
        strcpy(s1,intm);
        m=k;
        m++;

        hastlet=s1[0];

        for(t=0;t<26;t++)
        {
            if(complete[t].alph==hastlet)
            {      
                node=complete[t].next;
                if(node==NULL)
                {      
                    complete[t].next=create(s1);
                    node=complete[t].next;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {   while(!strcmp(node->s,s1))
                    {
                        node=node->next;
                        if(node->next==NULL)
                        {   flag++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!strcmp(node->s,s1))
                        (node->count)+=1;
                    if(flag)
                    {   node->next=create(s1);
                    }
                }       break;
            }
        }


    }
}

//displaying the word that are counted

for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{   node=complete[i].next;
if(complete[i].next!=NULL)
while(1)
{   printf("%s---%d",node->s,node->count);
    if(node->next==NULL)
        break;

}
}



getch();
}

struct wordcount * create(char *y)
{
struct wordcount *newnode;
newnode->s=y;
newnode->count=0;
newnode->next=NULL;
return newnode;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is incorrect:

```
char *c;
...
gets(c);
```

Using an un-initialized pointer `c` in `gets` function leads to a undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory for `c` which is one greater than the max number of characters you wish to store.

Same is the case with `intm`.

Also, use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) in place of `gets`

Comment: when i am giving (Input:hello hello hello) to this program when it is for the first iteration "h" hash code link will be null. and one word will be linked.the problem coming for me is when it went to second iteration it is considering as if the "h" hash code link is null ....can i know why it is?